# SSH asks password when invoke it in script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I have one master and four slave computers. I generated rsa public/private key on master PC. Then I copied publickey (`id_rsa.pub`) to slave machines as `authorized_keys`.

It doesn't ask password when I invoke SSH  like this on master PC's terminal:

```
ssh –o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null –o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@slave1
```

I wrote this script to automatically login slave machines without asking password.

```
SERVER_LIST=`cat /home/hduser/slaves` # slave1, slave2 ...

for host in $SERVER_LIST; do
host=hduser@$host 
ssh –t –o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null –o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host; 
done
```

SSH is asking slaves passwords when I use this script. I'm getting this message when use SSH with `-vv` option:

```
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
hduser@slave1's password:
```

I changed permissions on master PC and slave PC.

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/hduser    
sudo chmod 700 -R ~/.ssh
sudo chown hduser ~/.ssh
```

It doesn't ask password when I invoke SSH on terminal but It still asking password when invoke it in script. What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Who is the script running as? What user?

Comment: Logs suggest you're running the script as root; did you generate your SSH keys id_* and save them to /root/.ssh on the master?

Comment: `hduser` runs this script as root on Master PC.

Comment: No, I didn't generate public/private keys with `root`. I generated them with `hduser` as root. It works correctly if I invoke ssh on Master PC's terminal. It doesn't work in script.

Comment: Thk yout @ernie, It works after copied `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` under `/home/hduser/.ssh/` directory to `/root/.ssh/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH logs show that the login session is looking in /root/.ssh/ for the credentials, which implies your script is running as root.

Either copy your id_* files to /root/.ssh, generate the appropriate credentials as root, or run the script as the user where you have the credentials saved.

Comment: Is there a way to change this looking directory `/root/.ssh/` to `/home/hduser/.ssh/`?

Comment: Yes, run the script as `hduser` instead of in a su or sudo environment . . .